# Customize DELETE method in Spring Data repository

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

For some logging purpose, i'm using AspectJ to log CRUD operations, for the delete operation i'm supporting only `repository.delete(object)` so `repository.delete(id)` is not supported, but while using http DELETE call in Spring Data repository, i intercept `repository.findOne()` then `repository.delete(id)` calls.

**My Question**

How i could customize Http DELETE method in Spring Data repository to call `repository.delete(object)` not `repository.delete(id)`.

here's repository interface:

```
package com.geopro.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.geopro.entities.Product;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {

}
```

AspectJ code :

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
public void publicNonVoidRepositoryMethod() {
}

@Around("publicNonVoidRepositoryMethod()")
public Object publicNonVoidRepositoryMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    if (pjp.getArgs()[0].getClass().getName() == "java.util.Arrays$ArrayList"  || pjp.getArgs()[0].getClass().getName() == "java.util.LinkedList") {
        Iterable arr = (Iterable) pjp.getArgs()[0];
        return saveHistoriqueOperation2(pjp, arr);
    } else {
        Object objs = pjp.getArgs()[0];
        if (objs.getClass().getName() == "com.geopro.entities.HistOperation") {
            Object o = pjp.proceed();
            return o;
        }
        return saveHistoriqueOperation(pjp, objs);
    }

}
```

i'm managing cases where `objs` is an entity object, so all my delete operations are using `delete(entity_object)`, not `delete(id)`, i'm looking for a manner to modify function calls where http DELETE 'ressource_url/id' gets called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you kindly share some piece of code. It is not exactly clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just repository declaration wouldn't help. We need to know what expression you used. The methods which you wanted to intercept, and how the other method is getting intercepted.. Try to give some relevant information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with @RestResource(exported = false) on the delete(id) method?

I just created a simple project and it seems to work.

Here is the code of the repository class in my project

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    void delete(Long var1);

    @Override
    void delete(Product var1);
}
```

Comment: what would be URI for delete request in Postman or curl and my scanario is here <br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399225/unable-to-retrieve-spring-hateoas-embedded-resource-object-in-case-of-manytoman/43400328?noredirect=1#comment74352700_43400328